# alguien podría ayudarme a resolver este problema

Tags: javascript

He podido resolver e problema de distintas formas pero no se que falta a dicho código dejo el link del problema

https://codeable.pe/QDgfKXhUT4HYukaVHjjzczgA.html

esta es mi solución:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  var a = i,
    b = '';
  if (i % 3 == 0) {
    a = '';
    b += "Fizz"
  }
  if (i % 5 == 0) {
    a = '';
    b += "Buzz"
  }
  console.log(a + b);
}
```

Comment: 2 problemas: La condición de si es 3 y si es 5 y el el bucle recorre de 0 a 99.Tienes que añadir una condición al principio que complete las dos condiciones del 3 y el 5 (puedes añadir un `AND` o `&&` para añadir varias condiciones). Luego en el for tendrías que cambiar el `i=0` por `i=1` y `i<100` por `i<=100` de esa manera recorrería del 1 a 100 en vez de 0 a 99

Comment: nos muestras que has intentado tu?

Comment: si claro esta es mi solución:  for (var i=1; i <= 100; i++) {
  var a = i, b = '';
  if (i % 3 == 0){
    a = '';
    b += "Fizz"
  }
  if (i % 5 == 0){
    a = '';
    b += "Buzz"
  }
  console.log(a+b);
}

Comment: Si quieres mejorar la pegunta edítala e incluye las mejoras en ella, estos comentarios son mas para aclarar dudas que para ampliar la información de la pregunta. Además, las partes de código con el formato adecuado son más fáciles de entender.

Comment: gracias a todos por tomarse el tiempo

Comment: Nunca pongas un enlace a una página externa porque puede ocurrir, como en este caso, que el enlace se rompa con el tiempo y por tanto, nos quedamos sin poder saber a qué te refieres. En lugar de eso, puedes poner el enlace, pero también copia el contenido relevante en tu pregunta para que podamos saber de que se trata en caso de que el enlace deje de funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal sería que lo intentaras tú mismo y nos comentaras:

```
function message(n) {
  if (n % 3 === 0 && n % 5 === 0) {
    return "FizzBuzz";
  }
  else if (n % 3 === 0) {
    return "Fizz";
  } else if (n % 5 === 0) {
    return "Buzz";
  } else {
    return n;
  }
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  const msg = message(i);
  answerEl.textContent += msg;
}
```